# UIScrollView is not resizing when I setFrame

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I have a UIScrollView that I am dynamically adding labels and textfields to based on a csv file.  It is originally set on my view to have a frame of 0, 340, 100, 100.  I calculate the new frame in my code try to update that size with the code below.

```
[_svFields setScrollEnabled:YES];
[_svFields setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[_svFields setFrame:CGRectMake(frameX, frameY, frameWidth, frameHeight)];
[_svFields setContentSize:CGSizeMake(frameWidth, y)];
```

It correctly adds the labels and textfields to the scrollview however the scrollview itself isn't updated to the new frame and it is still at 0,340,100,100. I've tried it where I call [_svFields setNeedsDisplay]; after updating the frame and it still does nothing.  The values when I stop on setFrame are frameX=0, frameY=319, frameWidth=750, frameHeight=403, y=2152.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Edit: I am using the different size classes currently so disabling Autolayout isn't an option.  If that's the only way thanks for the help.  The reason I was setting the size in the first place was because these classes are constantly resetting my UIScrollView frame to 0,0,0,0 instead of the size I give it as I move and change other objects in the View.  Is there a fix to that issue that anyone knows of?

Edit2: I found a workaround for this.  By setting setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoContraits to YES for the UIScrollView it doesn't autosize and allows my set sizes to be used.
[_svFields setTranslatesAutoresizingMastIntoContraints:YES] before setting the frame coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Disable autolayout property for your UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very easy to use scrollViews with autolayout.

You can start with this template project:

https://github.com/annabd351/AutolayoutTemplate